# LinkedIn social sharing image not showing up when using og:image tag

Tags: seo, linkedin

For some reason, when I share a URL to my blog post on LinkedIn, the image specified in the `og:image` tag does not appear in the share LinkedIn post.

URL shared: https://robertcooper.me/post/feature-flags

`og:image` meta tag found in the page's head:

```html
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.robertcooper.me/api/og-image/Building%20with%20feature%20flags?readTime=6">
```

The LinkedIn post inspector confirms that the image won't show up when shared: https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/https:%2F%2Frobertcooper.me%2Fpost%2Ffeature-flags

[image]

---

Testing things out on other websites, I looked at how sharing this URL looks like: https://css-tricks.com/

This shows up correctly on LinkedIn (as confirmed by the LinkedIn post inspector: https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/https:%2F%2Fcss-tricks.com%2F).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image request is actually returning a 308 response, directing to:

`https://robertcooper.me:443/api/og-image/Building with feature flags?readTime=6`

Note the addition of the port and the `%20` s being returned to spaces.

Also, I seem to recall in the past that LinkedIn got upset if the og:image path didn't look like a file (e.g. ending in `.jpg` or `.png`).

Comment: Thanks a lot! The issue was both a redirect issue (`www` -> non `www`) and missing `.png` at the end of the URL.